# Android asset studio - Action Bar and Tab Icon Generator

Tags: android

I've used this site in the past to generate icons for launchers and action bars with success.

I'm trying to generate a white sync clip-art from within the action bar and tab icon generator section. It only wants to generate black images no matter what colour I select, is anybody else having issues or know how to fix it?

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&source.clipart=res%2Fclipart%2Ficons%2Fnotification_sync.svg&name=ic_action_notification_sync&theme=custom&color=fff%2C100

Answer (score 0):

turns out its a bug with the new version of chrome. I should of checked the github page first :(

https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio/issues/74